# how to fix error perl -e exit?

Tags: 14.04, perl

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "id_ID.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "id_ID.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "id_ID.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "id_ID.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "id_ID.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "id_ID.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "id_ID.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "id_ID.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "id_ID.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

how to fix it?

before u tell this repost
i already do

add line : into /etc/environment & /etc/default/locale

```
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

and do command :

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: i just forgot to reboot :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines to your `/home/username/.bashrc` file:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```